# Gitflow: Merging release bugfixes back to develop from master

Tags: git, git-flow

My question is around a very specific point in the gitflow process (as documented [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#finishing-a-release-branch)).

I've already merged bugfixes from `release/1.2` into `master`, and tagged appropriately.

Apart from how the history looks, what are differences between back-merging from `release/1.2` vs back-merging from `master` into `develop`.

I have tried both ways, and in my simple, contrived example I see no difference in `develop`, as I expected.

Are there dangers to this? Am I going to encounter messy issues later on? Am I missing something obvious? I suspect the answer may be to do with other features that have gone into `master`, but which should remain out of `develop` for the moment.

**merging release in to develop:**

[image]

**merging master in to develop:**

[image]

Comment: Could you include a diagram showing your flow?  Maybe someone who uses Git flow heavily would follow your description, but I don't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you merge `master` back into your develop, you will have all the `merge branch release/x.y into master` merge commits in your develop branch, while when merging the `release/x.y` branch itself, you only get the real changes.

Of course, this is more or less a cosmetic issue. But the merge direction is usually only from `develop` to `master`, never the other way around.

There are no real dangers except for said merge commits cluttering up your `develop` branch. If you stick to the flow, there should never be features in `master` that are not in `develop`, since hot fixes as well as release branches should always be merged into your `develop` as well as in `master`.

Comment: Good points. I don't think I intend to deviate from the process, this is more of a curiosity question.

Comment: Anyway, you have not answered question. Non-accepted answer below has more details and more deep explanations.

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading in that eventually all the merge commits end up in `develop` regardless.

Comment: Could you elaborate? As I understand and practiced GitFlow for years, these commits never end up in `develop` since there are never merges from `master` to `develop`, only the other way around.

Comment: @kowsky because hotfixes branch off of `master`, so they will include all of the merge commits that have been sitting on `master` since the last hotfix. When you complete the hotfix branch you merge it back to `develop`. I suppose if you never do hotfixes you may never have seen them... The first time I did a hotfix and saw this, was when I decided to switch to merging `master` back to `develop` and I've preferred that ever since.

Comment: @TTT You're right, hotfixes branch off and merge into `master`, but instead of merging them back to `develop`, we cherry-pick the relevant commit(s) to prevent the backwards merge. Feels cleaner to us, but after all it's not that important and just a nuance of how you implement the workflow.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there dangers to this? Am I going to encounter messy issues later on? Am I missing something obvious?

No dangers; no issues; and you're not missing anything. Merging `master` back to `develop` is (IMHO) the *slightly* better way to go, and there are no downsides. Either way you choose you will always end up with the same total number of merge commits in `develop`. The difference is only the timing of when those merge commits end up there. If you merge `release` back first you don't get all of the `release` to `master` merge commits until later, all in one shot when you do a hotfix. If you do `master` back to `develop` you see the recent merge commits right away. But there's an even bigger advantage of merging `master` back to `develop`:

At all times it's important to make sure all changes in `master` are also in `develop` or in `release` when it exists. (The only time they should ever be out of sync is during the completion of a `release` or `hotfix` branch.) Perhaps the easiest way to confirm `master` is synced up is to make sure the tip (top commit) in `master` is always in `develop`, or `release` when it exists. You could easily script that to run at some regular frequency and notify you if it's not true. That script is more complicated if you can't expect the tip commit of `master` to ever be in `release`.

Answer (score 3):

> I suspect the answer may be to do with other features that have gone into `master`, but which should remain out of `develop` for the moment.

Commits from `master` go into `develop` with next hotfix merge anyway. If there were real code change, it could be unexpected outcome and distort the hostfix content.

Merging stable branch (`master` in gitflow) into development branch (`develop` in gitflow) is known way in various git workflows. Bbitbucket Server (commercial solusion being sold by Atlassian) has a feature of [Automatic branch merging](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html). Git project itself always merges branch `maint` into `master` as there is some bugfix.

So I don't really see the reason why gitflow's author has chosen another way. It might be that there is no real rationale, it was just an accidental decision.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it so it doesnt look like master is ahead of develop in the list views. If you merge master down to develop instead of release branch and hotfix it will make it so master is never ahead of develop in list view and if it is you know something has gone wrong and needs to be fixed