# Using "git flow release finish" why merge master into develop not use the release branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

I have question about git flow operation. I watched [the post](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#release-branches) about the "Release branch". Finally, the release branch merged into master and develop respectively.  I also followed the commands, and the commit graph had been correct.

[image]

[image]

I used [gitflow-avh](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) or sourcetree to same operations, but the commit graph was different. Why the master branch merge into the develop branch not use the release branch?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merging `release` into `master`, instead of also merging `release` into `develop`, there are [some (minor) benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663604/184546) to instead merging `master` into `develop`. Note the resulting *state* is the same, but the extra merge commit on `master` will also exist on `develop`. Some implementations of Git Flow prefer to merge this way, one of which is `gitflow-avg`. The [FAQ](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/FAQ) actually crosses out a problem that is corrected by merging in this way (which is listed in the section "Why does git-describe not work for me?").