# Why we shouldn't merge main branch to develop branch in gitflow?

Tags: git, release, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

In [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) It suggests we should merge release/0.0.1 to the main branch and then merge to the develop branch.

> Once the release is ready to ship, it will get merged it into main and develop, then the release branch will be deleted. It’s important to merge back into develop because critical updates may have been added to the release branch and they need to be accessible to new features. If your organization stresses code review, this would be an ideal place for a pull request.

What if I merge release/0.0.1 to **main** and then **main** to develop? So I don't have to merge release/0.0.1 to main and develop. What's the issue if merge main to develop or philosophy behind merging the release branch twice?

Comment: You can, and arguably *should* prefer to merge `main` into `develop` instead of `release` into `develop`. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663604/184546)

Comment: @TTT So it was just accidental and no rational to merge the same PR into two different branches?

Comment: Note that either way you still have two merges. Years ago I asked Vincent Driessen (the creator of Git Flow) about his opinion of merging `master` into `develop` instead of `release` into both, and he said he does like the idea (and perhaps nowadays might even prefer it), and it's just a matter of preference. I didn't ask "why" he choose what he did but my guess is back in 2010 he probably didn't consider this option and therefore I assume he didn't consciously choose one over the other. The advantages are mostly academic; though I personally strongly prefer `master` into `develop`.

Comment: Since I know many people use the documented method, and I assume some of those people prefer that method, here's one advantage I can think of to use that method. If you are in the habit of automatically (or at least regularly) merging `release` into `develop` *before* you deploy to production, then when you actually do deploy to production you have only 1 merge to do instead of 2 (because you've already merged `release` into `develop`).